# Can't create service based database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have been programming in c# for some time and I used to program in Java before that but I have no knowledge of databases and servers. I was trying to create a SQL Server service-based database in Visual Studio Community 2015 but I get this error

[image: http://imgur.com/czrb5MB].

I have been searching online for hours and still I still haven't solved this problem. My SQL Server configuration manager looks a little different, I may not have all the components correctly installed but I don't know how to and which.

[image: http://imgur.com/JxUz8XT].

I have no problem reinstalling SQL Server Express. Please provide me the link where I can download and install/repair SQL Server Express.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: To diagnose, I'd start by making sure you are able to connect to the SQL Server with SQL Server Management Studio.  That will verify your installation to start.

Comment: You should also have SQL Server Data Tools installed in VS if you are intending to work with databases from within Visual Studio: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx

Comment: Scott Hanselman has collected all the [download links for SQL Server Express in various versions](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadSQLServerExpress.aspx) on his blog - great starting point.